# satisfies but for types

Tags: typescript, narrowing

TypeScript 4.9's `satisfies` operator is super handy, allowing narrowly typed values that still match a wide definitions.

```js
type WideType = Record<string, number>;

const narrowValues = {
    hello: number,
    world: number,
} satisfies WideType;
```

**Is there any way to define one type as satisfying another?**

```js
type WideType = Record<string, number>;

type NarrowType = {
    hello: 4,
    world: 5,
} satisfies WideType;
```

---

For types where you want very-specific values it's possible to go through a value to a type:

```js
type WideType = Record<string, number>;

const narrowValues = {
  hello: 4,
  world: 5,
} satisfies WideType;

type NarrowType = typeof narrowValues;
```

But it gets a little clunky if you're trying to deal with anything more complex:

```js
type TemplateType = `${number}-${number}`;
type UnionType = "FOO" | "BAR";

type WideType = Record<string, string>;

const narrowValues = {
  hello: "" as TemplateType,
  world: "" as UnionType,
  blah: "" as string
} satisfies WideType;

type NarrowType = typeof narrowValues;
```

Also it'd be great to be able to do this without creating any extra JS code.

Comment: You could define a utility `Satisfies` type that acts this way, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8YyrN).  Does that fully address your question?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Believe it does!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior using mapped types and conditional types in TypeScript:

```js
type WideType = Record<string, string>;

type NarrowValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TemplateType<any, any> | UnionType<any> ? T[K] : T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never;
}[keyof T];

const narrowValues: NarrowValues<WideType> = {
  hello: "FOO" as TemplateType<any, any>,
  world: "BAR" as UnionType<any>,
};
```

We define a mapped type `NarrowValues` that iterates over the keys of the given type `T`. For each key, it checks if the corresponding value is a `TemplateType` or `UnionType`. If it is, it uses the value directly; otherwise, it uses the value as a string. Finally, we create an object `narrowValues` that satisfies the `WideType` while using more complex types for the values.

This solution doesn't require extra JavaScript code and works purely with TypeScript types. However, it may be less readable and more complex than using the `satisfies` operator, which is designed to simplify type-safe configuration in TypeScript